# How to display image in webview with CSS

Tags: html, css, android-studio, media

In an Android app only displaying a webpage, I apply a custom CSS on the webview with a JS injection.
I do not have the possibility to edit the HTML.
Using the CSS, I wanted to add an image on the page with a background-image on a ::before pseudo-element.

I tried this on Chrome with a style editor extension, it works! But when applying the same CSS in Android Studio, all the code works but the image doesn't show.

On an element of the webpage' HTML, I apply a ::before pseudo-element.
::before has a width and an height, and I set background-image:('myurltothepic');

This works on Desktop Chrome, the image appears.

On Android Studio, all the CSS injected works as intended, except for the background-image in URL.

CSS:

```
&:before{
    background: url("http://guillaume.work/assets/images/showdown/showdownThk.png") !important;
    content: "";
    width: 80%;
    height: 130px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

JAVA:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        String currentUrl;

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            currentUrl = url;

            if (url.startsWith("http:") || url.startsWith("https:")) {
                return false;

            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {


            // Inject CSS when page is done loading
            injectCSS();

            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    });

    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

    webview.loadUrl("https://play.pokemonshowdown.com");
}

// Inject CSS method: read style.css from assets folder
// Append stylesheet to document head
private void injectCSS() {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("showdownFancy.css");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[inputStream.available()];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
        inputStream.close();
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(buffer, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
                "style.type = 'text/css';" +
                // Tell the browser to BASE64-decode the string into your script !!!
                "style.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                "parent.appendChild(style)" +
                "})()");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();


    }
    ;
}
```

There is no error messages, but the images in URL seem to not load at all.

I need help, thanks in advance